# Trim white spaces in MySQL using Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can we make so that when a user enters in a location, it trims out all the white spaces when it updates into the DB, myphpadmin? Would trim function work with INSERT INTO?

```html
         $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO locations(location_name) VALUES (%s)",
                $branch_location
            )
        );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
If anyone wants to know,

```
         $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO nzschoolinfo_locations(location_name) VALUES (%s)",
            str_replace(' ', '', trim($branch_location))
        )
    );
```

add `str_replace(' ', '', trim($branch_location))`

Comment: Your `str_replace` call removes *all* spaces. It doesn't just trim the string (trim removes whitespace only from the beginning and end). Also, your `str_replace` doesn't remove all whitespace, it just removes space characters. If you just need to trim whitespace from the beginning and end, the `trim` call is sufficient.

Comment: What about the middle?

Comment: Trim only removes whitespace from the beginning and end. That's generally what you want to do when filtering user input (spaces in the middle are often intentional and should stay in). When you use the word "trim" in your question, that's what you're implying. If you want to remove all whitespace from a string, you'd use something like `preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $str);`.